# My.computer can't access file after file.create

Tags: vb.net

I have some code to delete a file, make another one (so i can overwrite it) and write on it.

```
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("./pass")
            File.Create("./pass")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("./pass", MaskedTextBox1.Text, True)
```

When it gets to write the text it says :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file '[path]\pass' because it is being used by another process.
```

Is there a way to solve this or maybe a way to just overwrite the file without deleting and making it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> because it is being used by another process

That's not entirely accurate, it is in use by *your* process.  File.Create() returns a FileStream object.  You didn't call its Close() method so it is still in use.  File.Create().Close() would solve the problem.

But there's no point to using File.Create() here, the FileSystem.WriteAllText() already creates the file.  No point in deleting the file either, WriteAllText() overwrites the file.  So just remove the first two statements to fix your problem.

Comment: Great answer that describes the issue accurately.

Comment: But your suggestion does not work, File.Create().Close() still sees the file as being used by another process.

Comment: Then the exception message is probably accurate in your case.

Comment: Well, no for clarification the .Close() needs to be added to the Create statement, and not listed as a seperate line of code. You did not explicitly state that it should be, but I only point out that it is the addition of .Close() that fixes the OP code.