# creating then writing to a text file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text-files

I have button to create a text file and a textbox to write stuff to the text file when I press enter.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    path = "C:\Testing.txt"
    File.Create(path)
End Sub

 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf)
 End If
```

The file is created properly but when I want to write to it using the code above, I get an error.

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Testing.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Look at the description as you type `.Create` - it creates the file *and* opens a filestream for the file.  So it is already/still open later when you try to use `AppendAllText`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My.computer can't access file after file.create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891617/my-computer-cant-access-file-after-file-create)

Comment: You should also not use the root folder of `C:\` for testing or output - writing to files there can result in a permission denied exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
File.Create(path)
```

To this:

```
File.Create(path).Dispose()
```

However as stated before, you can cut all this out and simply use:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    path = "C:\Testing.txt"
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(path, TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.FILE.APPENDALLTEXT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true): `AppendAllText` will "Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file."